I got 5 Bitcoin from Bitcoin faucet in 2010
I just remembered that when I was about 11-12 I used Bitcoin faucet to get 5 bitcoins.
I remember 3 possible emails which I can use for that website, is there a possibility to somehow gain access to it?
